# Display Results from Database as a list within a texbox

Tags: php, ajax

I'm retrieving data on `keyup` from DB using the following script

```
  <script>
                $(function(){
                    $('.input').keyup(function(){
                        var a = $('.input').val();
                        $.post('actions/action_user_search.php',{"search":a},function(data){
                            //show results 
                            $('#display').html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });

    </script>
```

I would like to display the result(s) as a list inside the textbox and not below the textbox

[see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZQDw.png)

```
echo '<h1>Search User</h1>
    <form action= "actions/action_user_search.php" method="POST" >
        <input type="text" name="search" class="input">
        </form>
        <div id="display" style="margin-top:50px" ></div>';
```

How can I display the results in the textbox as a list and not using the way shown here (within the div id=display)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong selector. This code will set text to your textbox if the `data` is a string:

```
$('input[name=search]').val(data);
```

If response `data` is an HTML code, you have to parse it first, extract list items and then set to textbox